# Exporting Access data to pre-existing and pre-formatted Excel spreadsheets

Tags: excel, ms-access, vba

Good day all,
I am very new to Access and VBA, so some of these questions may seem elementary, but any help offered would be greatly appreciated... I am a member of a recruiting organization, and am trying to build a database system that will greatly increase our administrative efficiency and quality of life.  My organization insists on the use of Excel spreadsheets that are supplied to us to document our efforts and for our reports, thus ruling out the possibility of using the reports from Access.  I have the underlying database pretty well ironed out, but what I need help with is taking that data and putting it in specific cells within an existing excel spreadsheet.  Specifically, what steps do I need to tell access to do, how to select the appropriate worksheet, and how to select individual cells to send data to.  I also need to link all of this to a button on a form labeled, say, "Generate Applicant Log"... Additionally, I would like both the database and all applicable template spreadsheets we would need to be located in the same folder that I can lock, so that I can send the whole folder to another user and all necessary files are included, but they can't get into the folder to mess with stuff. I am concerned this will affect whatever coding I would use due to the changing file path names from user to user, so any help in figuring out a way to tell access how to find the spreadsheets relative to where the database is so it always works no matter who's computer the folder is on or where it is at in the same computer, would also be greatly appreciated... I apologize in advance for the length of this inquiry, and graciously appreciate any help in this matter! Thank you for your time!

Answer (score 0):

Rather than send data from Access to Excel, it is easier to pull data into Excel from Access.  In Excel, on the "Data" tab select "from other sources" and build a Microsoft Query.  I like to put the data into a spreadsheet and link the data into the sheet the user will see - I hide the original sheet.  This way you can put all of the data into the hidden sheet, and then move things for the reports you need.
Using this method, I bring measurement data from a database, show it to users that need to review it, and run VBA routines to evaluate the data and highlight the interesting / important data.  I also keep the users out of the original database. 
I have my database on a server and I cannot offer help on sending the database and files to the user.  I just send the file - they have access to the server and the data is refreshed each time the spreadsheet opens.

Comment: Your solution was actually my first idea, however I ran into significant roadblocks along the way.  Namely, we dont have access to a consolidated server or even a shared drive that would meet the requirements for storing privacy sensitive information, so my product has to be self contained and able to operate independently on any one users computer.  Secondly, the majority of my prospective users have extremely limited computer experience, so I need my system to work behind the scenes to generate the results the user needs with no more initiation than a button click.

Comment: Thank you for your answer.  I have since learned much about access and excel both, and now realize this question is ridiculously unanswerable.  I had done quite a bit at the time I asked it, but never broke into the VBA world at that time, so I didnt even know where to start or even what questions I should have been asking.  But now, I am still learning every day but I know that what I was trying to do would not have worked well and your answer would have been a far better approach, (and have used it successfully a few times since) so thank you!  If even almost three years later... :/